# Google MC Funnels - How to set up with OAuth2.0 key?

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I Downloaded the API from github but I fell so confuse about several points, So after take several tutors from the web, my question  remains, **Once i have the OAuth2.0 ID, how to put it, in my Downloaded PHP API ?**.

Some points to consider:

- Once i download de API, and try the examples, it says "you have to download it by composer".
- The examples, do not show how to get the **mcf:xxxxxx**  values from funnels API.

So, I am a little lost about how to set it up, thanks in advance! (please sorry my pour English)

Comment: Grab the v1-master branch if you dont want to use composer https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/v1-master

Comment: Now I realize that I have to use "service account" option in the google's console, to create a key. So, the questions change a little, but after a lot of reading, remains to me: how to set up this (download master) API, with "service account" I just created? Thanks for your patience!